# Skip specific modules during npm install

Tags: npm

In my development project I have `package.json` that contains 3 groups of dependencies:

- Standard dependencies from the public NPN repositories
- Dependencies from an internal development repository that requires a certain proxy configuration and permissions
- Dependencies from an internal financial repository that requires its own proxy and permissions

Our build integration machine is the only one set-up to be able to pull all dependencies, while all Dev machines cannot, which creates a nightmare of dependency installation.

---

Is it possible to tell NPM within the `install` command to install all except, and provide the list of modules in `package.json` to be skipped during the installation?

Otherwise, what is the best way to deal with such a situation, considering that getting all the proxies set up with all the permissions isn't realistic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here with a super late reply:

The short answer is no, npm was not designed for this. This adds a level of complexity that npm isn't willing to support. That being said, I wrote a package to do it.

My package is [install-subset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-subset), and can be installed globally with `npm install -g install-subset`

To use it, you build inclusion lists and exclusion lists for named installation subsets in your package.json like this:

```
"subsets": {
    "build": {
        "include": [
            "babel-cli",
            "dotenv"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "exclude": [
            "eslint",
            "lint-rules",
            "prettier"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then run `install-subset test`

This will temporarily rewrite your package.json to not install those packages excluded, then restore it (very similar to how lerna operates), which depending on the packages can save a lot of time and bandwidth.

Also works with yarn, is open source and issues/PRs are welcome.

Answer (score 16):

You can use another way like "optionalDependencies" described in the official documentation here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#optionaldependencies

Example:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some-package-name-1": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "some-package-name-2": "1.0.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "some-package-name-3": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

and call

```sh
npm install --no-optional
```

it will install only the following:

```
some-package-name-1, some-package-name-2
```

Comment: This *still* doesn't stop npm from minding its own business and NOT deleting packages that are needed simply because there isn't presently a way to locate them.  This makes me so CROSS!!!

Comment: In 2023 the command is `npm install --omit=optional`.